# C# Dynamically determine class properties based on configuration for comparison

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic-attributes

I have a configuration defined for duplicate check on each property in my model below

```
public class ConfigurationModel
{
    public GroupValue Value1 { get; set; }
    public GroupValue Value2 { get; set; }
    public GroupValue Value3 { get; set; }
    public GroupValue Value4 { get; set; }
    public GroupValue Value5 { get; set; }
}
public class GroupValue
{
    public bool duplicateCheck { get; set; }
}
```

I have the real class which has all the properties defined like Value1, Value2 etc, which we will call it as OrderModel

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public string Value4 { get; set; }
    public string Value5 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to include only those properties for duplicate check which have the respective flag in configuration set to true. Example

```
bool CheckDuplicate(OrderModel newOrder)
{
OrderModel existingOrder = //GetfromDB;
//Compare only those properties in newOrder and existingOrder which have duplicate check set to true in ConfigurationModel
}
```

Using reflection to getproperties by string name and then compare is what I had in mind, But wanted to check the best way to do it, keeping performance in mind as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
AK

Answer (score 0):

When I understand right, the attributes are not known at compile time?
In this case I think the best approach is to use the refelction. (By using the nameof() function to get the property from reflection objects, you get a kind of type safety instead of using a harcoded string).

On the otherhand, if you know your full attributes set at compile time, you may create a controlled duplicate check for the attributes, depending on settings in your ConfigurationModel.

EDIT:
Simple try a kind of hit test to the database:

```
bool CheckDuplicate(OrderModel newOrder)
{
  OrderModel existingOrder = //GetfromDB WHERE dbOrder.Value1 == newOrder.Value1 AND dbOrder.Value2 == newOrder.Value2 AND_SO_ON;
  if(existingOrder/*.FirstOrDefault() -> if IEnumerble is returned from DB*/ == null) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I know the full attribute at compile time itself. so controlled if checks like if(value1 duplicatecheck == true), then compare value1 attributes, similary repeat it 5 times and then do a final && on all 5 values? –

Comment: @KeenUser, yes something like this 
OR
a maybe better way is, to perform an exists query on the database (query with filter on all needed attributes of newOrder against the database). If no item is returned, the newOrder is the only one, if not you need to handle your duplication process